# How to create dynamic content/Pages using JSON files in Gatsby?

Tags: json, graphql, gatsby

I wish to create a complex routing in Gatsby using multiple JSON files:

First JSON file is based on routing:
**File Location:** */src/data/route.json*

```
[
  {
    type: "Article",
    title: "Post One",
    slug: "/post-one",
    data: "post-one.json"
  },
  {
    type: "Course",
    title: "Course One",
    slug: "/course-one",
    data: "course-one.json"
  },
  ...
]
```

It is the Json file which contains route data.
Now in `post-one.json` file contains all the required data about the post that is required to render the post.

**File Location:** */src/data/articles/post-one.json*
**Routes:** */post-one*

```
{
  title: "Post One",
  head: {
    title: "Some title here",
    image: "/path/to/image.jpg",
    description: "Some description here..."
  },
  body: {
    // Body data here
    ...
  }
}
```

But the main problem arises now as the courses is the collection of the different chapters.
Now for the main course page:
**File location :** */src/data/courses/course-name.json*
**Route is like:** */course-name*

```
{
  title: "Course One",
  head: {
    title: "Some title here",
    image: "/path/to/image.jpg",
    description: "Some description here..."
  },
  info: {
    // Some info about the course...
  },
  chapter: [
    {
      title: "chapter one",
      slug: "/:courseId/chapter-one",
      description: "Something about the chapter"
    },
    {
      title: "chapter two",
      slug: "/:courseId/chapter-two",
      description: "Something about the chapter"
    },
    ...
    //Multiple chapters in the same course
  ]
}
```

Now the chapters will have the data like
**File location :** */src/data/chapters/chapter-name.json* 
**Route:** */courseId/chapter-name*

```
{
  title: "Chapter one",
  description: "Some description here",
  body: {
    ...
    //Content for the body that can be rendered easily
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what the problem is. Could you sum it up and possible provide a repro?

Comment: @PowellYe what I simply mean is How can I add complex structure of Pages from Json files... where it contains multiple JSON files for routing: Like in route.json file it has routes to Articles and courses, but courses also have chapters, chapters are routed in courses.json file

Comment: Standard approach is to rely on filesystem paths which are translated into slugs. Have you tried it? And how about sourcing your content using markdown? Things like title and description could be defined in frontmatter. You can even leverage React components with `mdx` plugin.

Comment: @PavelYe the problem with markdown is that I want custom frontmatter but it has fixed fields, currently I am working on one of the solution that does not require GraphQL, instead creates pages using the Json file only. Anyway thanks for the help.